# Trouble understanding this findMinimum array method

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm sorting arrays in subclasses that inherit a couple of methods from a class with things like swap to switch indexes a method to find the minimum value, method to print etc, however for the findMinimum method, my teacher provided us with a pre-made code, but I'm having a little trouble understanding it, was hoping some of you would be able to help.
An array is inserted by the user in a main class

```
public int findMinimum(int[] array, int first){
    int minIndex = first;
    for(int i =0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]<array[minIndex]){
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```

What I'm having a hard time understanding is since `int first` is given no initial value isn't it considered null and therefore can't be used to check in the loop? How can `int minIndex` be set equal to null?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int first` is a function parameter, so it will have an initial value when you call this function. You will call it with some array and initial assumed index of min:

```
myMinimum = findMinimum(myArray, 0)
```

In this case it actually doesn't make much sense, because minimum of a function will not depend on this parameter. I'd rewrite it as:

```
public int findMinimum(int[] array){
    int minIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] < array[minIndex]){
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```

See, I also skip the very first value because it is an initial minimum by default.

Comment: so aslong as you declare the parameter in the function() it will have an initial value?

Comment: No. It will not have an initial value, the value will be assigned to it at the moment function is called.

Comment: Think of f(x) = sin(x). Here x is not defined, but this is the whole idea, now you can call it as f(0.2) and get a value from it or whatever other parameter.

Comment: Gotcha, will definitely help in the future, probably would've learned better too if my teacher didn't just supply us with this and said "use it" lol

Answer (score 0):

When you call this method in your code, you supply an initial value for both `array` and `first`, such as this...

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] myArray = new int[]{2,5,10,30};
    int theMinimum = findMinimum(myArray,5);
    }
```

The variable `first` will always have a value, it just depends on what is passed through by the method call. In the example above, the value of `first` is `5`.

Maybe this is where you're getting confused... Your code is a method - it only gets run when you call the method in your code, as in the above example. If you don't call the method `findMinimum()`, then this code will never be run. The exception to this is your `main()` method, which is a special method that is understood my the Java JVM as being the entry point, the first bit of code that is run. All other methods need to be called, and passing through the values it requires (in this case, passing through values for `array` and `first`)